# How do I quickly and easily resize images in posts?

Tags: support, images

I've uploaded an image from my camera, and its *huge*.  Now people are telling me that they want it smaller so they can download it quickly or without eating up too much mobile data.  How can I provide this smaller image without jumping through too many hoops and yet still provide the large image so people can see that general noise profile I'm talking about?

Answer (score 1):

As part of imagur, there are two additional file names that are uploaded.

Here's an image from Wikipedia: [Daisies](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/archive/3/3e/20110417183207%21Daisies-Focus.jpg) - its big.  3872 x 2592 pixels and 2.38 megabytes.

Just a straight upload (https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6DfH.jpg) of the image downloads the full image and leaves it up to your browser to resize it:

```
[![Daisies][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6DfH.jpg
```

With a little bit of juggling of that markdown, and putting the 'm' after the file name:

```
[![Daisies][2]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6DfH.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6DfHm.jpg
```

We now get:

[image: Daisies]

The image links to the [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6DfH.jpg) file and displays the [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6DfHm.jpg) file.  The [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6DfHm.jpg) file is 320px on its widest side (width in this case) and so is now a 320 px by 214 px image and is only 18 kilobytes.

While its less useful for Stack Exchange than it is for Imgur itself, there is another file size provided that is a small square - the 's' size.

```
![Daisies][3]

  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6DfHs.jpg
```

gives us:

[image: Daisies]

which is a 90x90 px cropped image which is most useful for gallery type situations where you want a bunch of them to line up nicely:

[image: Daisies]
[image: Daisies]
[image: Daisies]
[image: Daisies]
[image: Daisies]
[image: Daisies]
[image: Daisies]
[image: Daisies]
[image: Daisies]
[image: Daisies]
[image: Daisies]
[image: Daisies]
[image: Daisies]
[image: Daisies]

This can all be done just by changing the file name of the file that is linked to on imgur.